# BIVS for Indian citizens applying outside of India

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I'm an Indian citizen applying for an Irish visa outside of India and I'm thinking of visiting the UK as well. The BIVS ( British-Irish Visa Scheme ) FAQ as of Feb 2015 says that in order to visit the UK with the same visa, I have to apply in India. Does anyone know if this is still true?

Answer (score 3):

The British-Irish Visa Scheme (BIVS, or its formal title: *Ministerial Authorisation under Schedule 3, Part 4, paragraph 17 (4)(a) of the Equality Act 2010*) is currently available to Indian and Chinese nationals. Other nationalities may (or may not) be added in October 2016 or in April 2017 before Parliament rises.

In order to qualify the applicant must use one of the Visa Application Centres in India or China. Applications will not be accepted outside of those locations.

> Does anyone know if this is still true?

Yes, it is still true and will continue to be true for a long time (we're talking 2020 or thereabouts).

More info at the [BIVS Guidance Site](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme#visa-application-centres)